# Link Subreport to matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a matrix like below. years on columns and countries on rows.

```
Countries  2001    2002
US         100     400
UK         200     290
IR         300      89
```

I have a requirement of creating a subreport which shows Invoice details. When I click 100 (US-1002) on my main report I have to show all the 100 Invoices. I tried this way:

Since I am doing count for InvoiceID in matrix, I tried using `Join(Fields!InvoiceID,", ")` expression on the data test box action(Go to report). On the other side I created a subreport with multivalue parameter. But this approach dint work. I found that Join will not work with data rows as it expect arrays.

Later I used `Join(LookupSet(1,1,Fields!Name.Value, "DatasetName")," / ").` I could join the invoice ids but the problem is , this expression joins all the invoice ID in complete dataset. I just need US-2001 cell (100) invoice ids only to take to my subreport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like the easiest thing to do would be to set up the subreport to take two parameters, *Country* and *Year*, instead of trying to pass the list of invoices.

The subreport can then report all the invoices for a particular *Country* and *Year* combination.

It would be simpler to just set up the drillthrough to accept the two fields for its parameters, as above, instead of try to work out an expression for all the invoices in a particular cell's scope.